# DateDifference converted into Days Hours and Seconds - Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, varchar

I am trying to perform the below mentioned code from `Microsoft SQL server` to `snowflake` however, am successful so far. Can someone help please?

`MSSQL Code`

```
convert(varchar(10),(DATEDIFF(s,A.Date_Time,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))/86400) + 'Days '
    + convert(varchar(10),((DATEDIFF(s,A.Date_Time,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))% 86400) /24) + 'Hours ' 
    + convert(varchar(10),(((DATEDIFF(s,A.A.Date_Time,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) % 86400) %3600)/60) + 'Mins' 
as [Waiting Pending Time]
```

`Snowflake` - here you may find the first line only as am testing atm

```
convert(to_varchar(10),(datediff(second,a.DateTime,current_timestamp)/86400) + "'Days'") as datediff
```

Can someone help pls?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to calculate them manually, DATEDIFF can handle it:

```
with mytable1 as (
select '2021-01-02 15:30' Date_Time )
select DATEDIFF( days, Date_Time, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  )  || ' Days ' ||
       DATEDIFF( hours, Date_Time, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  ) %  24  || ' Hours ' ||
       DATEDIFF( second, Date_Time, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  ) % 60 || ' Seconds ' AS result
from mytable1;


+-----------------------------+
|           RESULT            |
+-----------------------------+
| 195 Days 14 Hours 6 Seconds |
+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: thank you for your comment but that is not what exactly I need. The way you worked it, it got to the number of days in all scenario. What I would need is the results would be: 195 Days 23Hours 3180seconds. How many days; hours and seconds have passed together